# France, georeferencing with postal codes not working in CartoDB

Tags: carto, postal-code, geocoding, france

CartoDB is not georeferencing many of my locations in France. I am using postal codes, and specifying all of them are in France. CartoDB is able to georeference only about half of them. Any ideas?

Comment: I know it's an extra step but have you tried to pop them in here http://www.doogal.co.uk/BatchGeocoding.php? It will at least verify your postcodes as well as generate co-ordinates

Answer (score 1):

[This is the information available](http://team.cartodb.com/u/iriberri/viz/d6ded7b2-d789-11e4-a17f-0e6e1df11cbf/embed_map) for polygon geometries for zipcodes in France, so I recommend you to check if your data is there. The dataset is available [here](http://team.cartodb.com/u/iriberri/tables/postal_code_polygons/public).

If you're using the georeferenciation as points, could you share the table or a couple of zipcodes which are not working?

There are several possibilities here:

- Zipcode data is not recognized
- Zipcode data is not in CartoDB geocoding database
- Your account run out of quota while geocoding
- Internal error